# Sublime Text 2, faster alternative to find and replace regex?

Tags: sublimetext2

```
$_POST['daily_limit'];
$whatever = $_POST['smoke'];
$_POST['soup'] + $_POST['cake'];
```

to

```
$this->input->post('daily_limit');
$whatever = $this->input->post('smoke');
$this->input->post('soup') + $this->input->post('cake');
```

In this example, is there any faster way to switch from `$_POST[]` to `$this->input->post()` without writing up a regular expression find and replace? I don't care if it takes multiple steps. Writing the regex for this (find: `\$_POST\[(.*?)\]` replace: `\$this->input->post\($1\)`) takes longer than changing them all manually (maybe I'm just not good at regex). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### @nnnn I did a variation of your version to remove the wtfh4xxy part.

select:`$_POST`

<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f3</kbd>

type: `$this->input->post(`

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>

type: `)`

Sublime text ftw!

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a brash assumption here, that you have only one variable within each pair of brackets and that the variables only contain alphanumeric characters. `['soup'+'bacon']` will break this trick, as will `['soup-with-bacon']`.

With your cursor, highlight an instance of `$_POST[` - nothing else.

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> if you're on Windows/Linux (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> in Mac?)

Try to scroll through and see if everything that's selected is everything you want to replace.

Type `$this->input->post(` - nothing else.

Press <kbd>→</kbd> to move all cursors to the right of the first quote.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> (this is the only remotely wtfh4xxy part of the process, and only if you're not used to navigating by word with the cursor) to navigate over the variable.

Press <kbd>→</kbd> twice to move all cursors to the right of the next quote.

Replace the <kbd>]</kbd>with a <kbd>)</kbd>.